# create Notification in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to yii. I have created two table, `user` and `notification`. The table `notification` has `userid` as a foreign key. I want to create notification against user in user model just like I get notification from user model

```
 public function getnotifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Notification::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function in your model.

```
public function addNotification() {
    $notification = new Notification();
    $notification->user_id = $this->id;
    $notification->message = "Notification";
    $notification->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the name of your function ( should be **getNotifications()** not **getnotifications()** ), I see nothing wrong in your code.

```
public function getNotifications()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Notification::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

What is the problem now?

Comment: how i create new notification ?

Comment: This function is not to create a new notification. If you want to create a notification you need to build a new Notification's model in your controller. Please go and read the doc before . [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html)